# Java self unserialization

Tags: java, serialization, gson, this, final

I am trying to write a class, that has exportToString and importFromString methods. ExportToString serializes this class to JSON string:

```
public String exportToString() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(this);
    return json;
}
```

I need to write importFromString(String str). The problem is that "this" variable is final and I can't reassign this value completely. This is what I have:

```
public void importFromString(String str) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object obj = gson.fromJson(str, this.getClass());
    this = (PlayerData) obj;          // ERROR: cannot assign value to final variable this
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: importFromString should be a static method returning a new instance of PlayerData.

Comment: You can either return a new `PlayerData` or update every single variable of the current object to reflect the data from json

Comment: public static PlayerData importFromString(String str) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Object obj = gson.fromJson(str, this.getClass());
        return (PlayerData) obj;
    }

Is it correct?

Comment: ortis, Can I do this with Java Reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do what you want is to make the second method static and return an instance of the object represented in the string:

```
public static PlayerData importFromString(String str) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Object obj = gson.fromJson(str, PlayerData.class);
  return (PlayerData) obj;
}
```

You then invoke it as follows:

```
PlayerData obj = PlayerData.importFromString(someString);
```

Comment: Or possibly make both methods static? It is probably a good idea to separate the serialization/deserialization-logic from the actual business-object. What if you need to serialize it to some other format (e.g. XML), should PlayerData know of that to?

Comment: Agreed, but the style of the question suggests that this may be a little advanced at this stage! Getting the code compiling is always a good start...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
public static PlayerData importFromString(String str) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object obj = gson.fromJson(str, PlayerData.class);
    return (PlayerData) obj;
}
```

Comment: You need to return it!